# the model learned, but cannot predict?

Tags: linear-regression, pytorch

I follow the tutorial to write some linear regression code about boston price, it worked very well and the loss became smaller, when I wanted to paint the graph in matplotlib, I found the graph not showed as what in my mind.

I searched,but could not solve my question.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    boston = load_boston()
    col_names = ['feature_{}'.format(i) for i in range(boston['data'].shape[1])]
    df_full = pd.DataFrame(boston['data'], columns=col_names)

    scalers_dict = {}
    for col in col_names:
        scaler = StandardScaler()
        df_full[col] = scaler.fit_transform(df_full[col].values.reshape(-1, 1))
        scalers_dict[col] = scaler

    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_full.values, boston['target'], test_size=0.2, random_state=2)

    model = torch.nn.Sequential(torch.nn.Linear(x_train.shape[1], 1), torch.nn.ReLU())

    criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='mean')
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)

    n_epochs = 2000

    train_loss = []
    test_loss = []
    x_train = Variable(torch.from_numpy(x_train).float(), requires_grad=True)
    y_train = Variable(torch.from_numpy(y_train).float())

    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        y_hat = model(x_train)
        loss = criterion(y_hat, y_train)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        epoch_loss = loss.data ** (1/2)
        train_loss.append(epoch_loss)
        if (epoch + 1) % 250 == 0:
            print("{}:loss = {}".format(epoch + 1, epoch_loss))

    order = y_train.argsort()
    y_train = y_train[order]
    x_train = x_train[order, :]

    model.eval()

    predicted = model(x_train).detach().numpy()
    actual = y_train.numpy()
    print('predicted:", predicted[:5].flatten(), actual[:5])
    plt.plot(predicted.flatten(), 'r-', label='predicted')
    plt.plot(actual, 'g-', label='actual')
    plt.show()
```

why the predict were the same result like [22.4413, 22.4413, ...],
in the picture, it's a horizontal line.
I'm a very beginner to deeplearning, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: This is unrelated, but the [Variable API is deprecated](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#variable-deprecated) -- you might want to use a newer tutorial to use the tensor API.

Comment: @erip thanks a lot for your answer . but sorry for not catching you about the 'unrelated', the x_train is unrelated to the predicted? May I ask for more detail information! thanks. and any recommendation of the tutorials?